# File upload more than 3Gib not working in Apache in Ubuntu

Tags: php, apache

I want webserver apache2 in Ubuntu to accept file upload file which is less than 8GB. I have set memory_limit, upload_max_filesize and post_max_size more than 8GB in */etc/php5/apache2/php.ini*

I want to upload 3.7Gib which is an iso file. It is not accepting more than 3Gib.

Comment: Are you running 32- or 64-bit PHP?

Comment: Make sure your settings are active by checking them via `phpinfo();`.

Comment: Settings are correct.

Comment: It's probably [this know bug](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=44522) where file uploads > 2 GB are not possible. This bug is fixed with PHP 5.6.

Comment: More info: http://cweiske.de/tagebuch/php-large-file-uploads.htm

Comment: @bitWorking good to know that php 5.6 released on 2 oct 2014. can you guide me simply installing php5.6 in ubuntu terminal? Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You may have [Suhosin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suhosin) enabled. To verify if it's enabled, create a file with following content and execute it:

```
<?php phpinfo() ?>
```

When you execute it in a web browser, take a look if you have Suhosin enabled.

If it's enabled, you will need to update `suhosin.memory_limit` value in your configuration.

Comment: It seems like suhosin is enabled. in phpinfo it reads *This server is protected with the Suhosin Patch 0.9.10
Copyright (c) 2006-2007 Hardened-PHP Project Copyright (c) 2007-2009 SektionEins GmbH*. What does update suhosin.memory_limit means?

Comment: It is the same as "standard" `memory_limit` from php.ini, but all the Suhosin's values take precedence over standard php.ini values.

Answer (score 0):

Is the servers hard disc configured to use FAT32? If so this could be the reason. Reinstall Ubuntu using NTFS or create a new partion using NTFS.

Comment: Can you please give me alternative solution?

Comment: So this was not the case?